# Jquery Slide Toggle

Tags: jquery, html, css, xhtml

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is a slide toggle effect but not quite.

For example, I have a div which is set to a height of 200px and a anchor with a nested img tag. When a user clicks on the image the div will expand to a height of 500px and display the nested content which is within a ul.

To close the div there is a close icon on the bottom right which is an anchor containing a background image. When clicked the div will slide back to its previous height of 200px.

All suggestions are welcome

Here is my HTML to help:

[image]

Thanks,

Jordy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
var $getStarted = $('#getstarted');
$('#open img').click(function(){
  if($getStarted.hasClass('opened')) {
    $('#close').trigger('click');
  } else {
     $getStarted.animate({height:'+=300px'},500,function(){
      // you're open
        $getStarted.addClass('opened');
     });
  }
  return false;
});
$('#close').click(function(){
  if($getStarted.hasClass('opened')) {
    $getStarted.animate({height:'-=300px'},500,function() {
      // you're closed again
       $getStarted.removeClass('opened');
    });
  }
  return false;
});
```

How about this?

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/huF73/

Thanks,
MyStream

Comment: Thanks MyStream - will give it a go and let you know! :-)

Comment: Hah yeah I have made that change ;-)

Comment: MyStream - thankyou for your code, only issue is that every time I click on #open img the div keeps expanding by 300px and another 300px which pushes the content down - any way to make this not happen?

Comment: Hi Jordy, I've updated the answer to only open if not 'opened' and if you click it while it's 'opened' it triggers it to close.  Does that work better?

Comment: Hi Jordy, it does now - I typed 'getStarted' as 'getstarted' in the close function - 2nd line - try here: http://jsfiddle.net/huF73/ to experiment.

Comment: Thank you for all your help so far MyStream very much appreciated. Would you happen to know how to make the inner content I have which is the #gs-list-cat to hide on close and then show on expand?

Comment: No need - I've sorted it using .show() and .hide() - thanks for all your help!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

toggle();
Or if you want it a bit shorter:

```
function toggle(elm)
{
    var height = document.getElementById(elm);
    if(height == 200) {
        elem.style.height = 500;
    }

    if(height == 500) {
        elem.style.height = 200;
    }
    return false;
}
```

you can use this function via the onclick="toggle('yourElementToToggle')" of an <a> Tag

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.panel_button").click(function(){
        $("div#panel").animate({
            height: "100%"
        })
                $("div#main").hide();



    }); 

   $("div#hide_button").click(function(){
        $("div#panel").animate({
            height: "0px" 
        }, "fast");
                $("div#content").show();


   });  

});
```

BTW, for the above, you can change the value of the height to the desired value.

CSS:

```
.panel_button1 a {
YOUR STYLING HERE } /* for the exit button */

.panel_button {
width: YOUR VALUE HERE;
position: relative; } /* for the activation button styling */

.panel_button a {
YOUR STYLING HERE }
/* for the activation button styling */

#panel {
position: fixed;
width: VALUE OF YOUR CHOICE;
height: 0%; /*THIS CANNOT CHANGE UNLESS YOU WANT IT TO START AT A SPECIFIC HEIGHT. IF YOU WANT IT HIDDEN, DO NOT CHANGE IT*/ 
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 25;
background-color: COLOUR OF YOUR CHOICE;
} /* drop down colour */

#panel_contents {
height: VALUE OF YOUR CHOICE;
width: VALUE OF YOUR CHOICE;
position: absolute;
    z-index: 999; } /* drop down text */

#content {
CONTENT STUFF HERE }
```

Application:

```
Activation: <br> <div class="panel_button" style="display: visible;"><a href="#panel">blahblahblah</a></div>
```

Content & Exit button:

```
 <div id="panel"> 
<div class="panel_button1" id="hide_button" style="display: visible;"><a href="#">EXIT BUTTON TEXT OR STUFF.</a></div>
  <div id="panel_contents">
WHAT YOU SEE WHEN THIS THING DROPS DOWN. LIKE TEXT STUFF. 
</p>
</div> 
</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that I use in the situation of FAQ's, but works exactly as you describe.

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ToggleFAQ(faq) {
        $("#faq" + faq).slideToggle(500);
    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="ToggleFAQ('1')">QUESTION HERE</a>
<div id="faq1">
    <p>
        ANSWER HERE
    </p>
    <p>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="ToggleFAQ('1')">- Hide</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

The div holding the answer (faq1) is hidden from the start. You can set a class or however you want to hide it in the beginning.

Good Luck!